# JNLP file opens as xml file on browser

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Through javaws the jnlp file is tested and it runs fine. But using a browser it only opens the JNLP file as a xml file and does nothing when the url present in the codebase and href of the .jnlp file is entered.

How do I get to download the jar and run it through browser when the required url is entered?

Comment: Probably your web server is serving the file with the wrong Content-Type header. In order to be able to tell you how to fix that we need to know what web server software you're using.

Comment: I am using HTTPD Apache web server in CentOS environment.

Answer (score 2):

Probably Apache is serving the `.jnlp` file with the wrong `Content-Type`, so the browser doesn't recognise it as Java Web Start.  You need to add some configuration to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
AddType application/x-java-jnlp-file .jnlp
AddType application/x-java-archive-diff .jardiff
```

(find the existing `AddType` directives and add these lines there) and then restart httpd to make it re-read the config.

[Reference](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#apachemime) (this refers to `.htaccess` but if you have permission to edit the main configuration file then that will give better performance)

Comment: Thank You Ian Roberts,

Now the .jnlp file on the browser comes with a question mark icon but on clicking it still opens it as a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would second the previous answer: Yes, make sure you're server sends the right MIME type. After updating the configuration, test that it sends the right headers using e.g. wget:

```
wget --save-headers http://..../x.jnlp -O -
```

And look for the headers with "Content-Type"

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1155 (1.1K) [application/x-java-jnlp-file]
Saving to: `STDOUT'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 09:38:05 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"1155-1402308032000"
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Jun 2014 10:00:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-java-jnlp-file
Content-Length: 1155
Keep-Alive: timeout=1200, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Failing that, in Firefox Preference under Applications, find "JNLP file" and select the `javaws` executable, so that it will use that to "open" the JNLP file. The Java WebStart executable is called `javaws.exe` on Windows.